# How do I select multiple fields in jq?

Tags: jq, ndjson

My input file is newline delimited JSON (`ndjson`) looking something like this:

```
{
  "login": "dmaxfield",
  "id": 7449977,
  ...
}
{
  "login": "dmaxfield",
  "id": 7449977,
  ...
}
```

I can get all the `login` names with this : `cat members | jq '.[].login'` but I have not been able to crack the syntax to get both the `login` *and* `id`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your expected output should look like? There are many ways in which the login/id pairs could be represented.

Answer (score 353):

You can use `jq '.[] | .login, .id'` to obtain each login followed by its id.

Comment: The users' sample input does look like a stream of objects, but because of the sample script they provide, I'm assuming it's wrapped in an array which they omitted.

Comment: @SantiagoLapresta: There is no need for that assumption. `jq` works great with a sequence of objects - no need for the array wrapper. The `...` strings and the last trailing comma need removal, but I consider that to be implied.

Comment: `jq '.[] | .login, .id'` - this creates two output records, one for .login and one for .id.

Comment: Or if you only want those two fields to be displayed. `jq '.[] | {login, id}'`

Comment: @CameronTaggart, what if I want to display `login.name`? `jq '.[] | {login.name, id}'` does seem to work, what's the proper way, please?

Comment: @zyxue I posted a solution which would work in order to select indented fields (please see below)

Comment: @zyxue This works: `jq '.[] | {name: .login.name, id}'`

Comment: this doesn't work if I try to keep the output sorted by display name though, e.g. `jq ".services[] | .displayName, .serviceId" services.json | sort -f`

Answer (score 160):

This works for me:

```
> echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' | jq '{a,b}'
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
```

Comment: This is simple and exactly does what I wanted to do: have multiple input objects/hashes and take only some values of them, while also outputting them as objects.

Comment: Now I can use this on my digital photos:  `ls *jpg | xargs -n 1 exiftool -json | jq  '{ SourceFile,CreateDate,CreationDate,Make,Model,DateTimeOriginal,SceneType,FileAccessDate,FileModifyDate,FileInodeChangeDate,SceneCaptureType,ModifyDate }'`

Comment: Notice that you don't prefix the attribute by `.`. This took me a while to realize.

Comment: Just what I needed! I wonder if there is a way to make it work with nested objects.

Answer (score 51):

Just provide one more example here (jq-1.6):

Walk through an array and select a field of an object element and a field of object in that object

```
echo '[{"id":1, "private_info": {"name": "Ivy", "age": 18}}, {"id":2, "private_info": {"name": "Tommy", "aga": 18}}]' | jq ".[] | {id: .id, name: .private_info.name}" -

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Ivy"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Tommy"
}
```

Without the example data:

```
jq ".[] | {id, name: .private_info.name}" -
```

`.[]`: walk through an array

`{id, name: .private_info.name}`: take .id and .private_info.name and wrap it into an object with field name "id" and "name" respectively

Comment: wrapping into object to maintain structure/key names is great, just what I am looking for

Answer (score 27):

In order to select values which are indented to different levels (i.e. both first and second level), you might use the following:

```
echo '[{"a":{"aa":1,"ab":2},"b":3,"c":4},{"a":{"aa":5,"ab":6},"b":7,"c":8}]' \
     | jq '.[]|[.a.aa,.a.ab,.b]'

[
  1,
  2,
  3
]
[
  5,
  6,
  7
]
```

Answer (score 15):

### For jq >= v1.7

The builtin function [`pick`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#pick) is useful to slice objects (i.e. projection).

```console
$ cat example.ndjson | jq -c 'pick(.login, .id)'
{"login":"dmaxfield","id":7449977}
{"login":"eiffel","id":7449978}
```

Nested objects can be handled nicely, too.

```console
$ cat example.ndjson | jq -c 'pick(.login, .id, .nested.obj)'
{"login":"dmaxfield","id":7449977,"nested":{"obj":1.23}}
{"login":"eiffel","id":7449978,"nested":{"obj":4.56}}
```

If your input is formatted as JSON instead of NDJSON, prepend the script with `.[]`.

```console
$ cat example.json | jq '.[] | pick(.login, .id)' | jq -s '.'   
[
  {
    "login": "dmaxfield",
    "id": 7449977
  },
  {
    "login": "eiffel",
    "id": 7449978
  }
]
```

### For jq < v1.7

Use `{ login, id }`, which is a shorthand for `{ login: .login, id: .id }`.

```console
$ cat example.ndjson | jq -c '{ login, id }'                
{"login":"dmaxfield","id":7449977}
{"login":"eiffel","id":7449978}
```

For nested objects, write like this:

```console
$ cat example.ndjson | jq -c '{ login, id, nested: { obj: .nested.obj } }'
{"login":"dmaxfield","id":7449977,"nested":{"obj":1.23}}
{"login":"eiffel","id":7449978,"nested":{"obj":4.56}}
```

For normal JSON files:

```console
$ cat example.json | jq '.[] | { login, id }' | jq -s '.'
[
  {
    "login": "dmaxfield",
    "id": 7449977
  },
  {
    "login": "eiffel",
    "id": 7449978
  }
]
```

### Notes

I used the following NDJSON file and JSON file.

```console
$ cat example.ndjson 
{ "login": "dmaxfield", "id": 7449977, "foo": true, "nested": { "obj": 1.23 } }
{ "login": "eiffel", "id": 7449978, "foo": false, "nested": { "obj": 4.56 } }
$ cat example.json 
[
  { "login": "dmaxfield", "id": 7449977, "foo": true, "nested": { "obj": 1.23 } },
  { "login": "eiffel", "id": 7449978, "foo": false, "nested": { "obj": 4.56 } }
]
```