# JQ: How to get just part of a JSON object?

Tags: json, jq

How can I get my wanted output? I can't figure out how to preserve the object names (keys).

I'm new to jq and I tried several flavors of jq's select/flatten/map/","/"keys as $k".../etc. but I'm not getting anywhere.

### Input

```
$ echo '{"apples": {"color":"green",  "count":3}, "bananas": {"color":"yellow", "count":4}, "cherries": {"color":"red"}}' \  
  | jq .
{
  "apples": {
    "color": "green",
    "count": 3
  },
  "bananas": {
    "color": "yellow",
    "count": 4
  },
  "cherries": {
    "color": "red"
  }
}
```

### Actual Output

This is the best I got but the object names are gone:

```
$ echo '{"apples": {"color":"green",  "count":3}, "bananas": {"color":"yellow", "count":4}, "cherries": {"color":"red"}}' \  
  | jq '.apples, .cherries'
{
  "color": "green",
  "count": 3
}
{
  "color": "red"
}
```

### Expected Output

This is what I want:

```
{"color":"yellow", "count":4}, "cherries": {"color":"red"}}' \  
  | jq #some-jq-magic-here
{
  "apples": {
    "color": "green",
    "count": 3
  },
  "cherries": {
    "color": "red"
  }
}
```

Comment: In your case: `{apples, cherries}`

Comment: I'm not sure the selected https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834519/how-do-i-select-multiple-fields-in-jq is an ideal duplicate target. That question is more vague than this one and while the desired answer _is_ there it's neither the accepted nor the most upvoted answer at present.

Answer (score 3):

## jq '{apples, cherries}' instead of jq '{.apples, .cherries}'

I tried with dots first: `jq '{.apples, .cherries}'`. That did NOT work.

But WITHOUT the dots it works just fine:

```
$ echo '{
  "apples":   { "color":"green",  "count": 3 },
  "bananas":  { "color":"yellow", "count": 4 },
  "cherries": { "color":"red" }
}' | jq '{apples, cherries}'
{
  "apples": {
    "color": "green",
    "count": 3
  },
  "cherries": {
    "color": "red"
  }
}
```

*Related:* [How do I select multiple fields in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834519/how-do-i-select-multiple-fields-in-jq)

Comment: RE "*I tried with dots first*", `{apples, cherries}` is short for `{apples: .apples, cherries: .cherries}`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '...' | jq 'with_entries(select([.key] | inside(["apples", "cherries"])))'
```

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/46293052/9216229

Comment: Thanks. That works! But I'll never remember that syntax. So I went for a more concise version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69825482/4247268

Comment: You could also use `IN()`: `with_entries(select(.key | IN("apples","cherries")))`. But it is easiest to just `{apples, cherries}`.